# Oracle replacing null using NVL check for empty rows

Tags: oracle, null, nvl

I am running a query to retrieve an integer but want to put a check for nulls. If null I want the query to return 0. How can I do that? I tried this below but it's not working

```
select NVL(A_COUNT, 0) from MYTABLE where VEH_YEAR = '2003';
```

If A_COUNT is null I want the query to return 0. In the above case I don't have a value 2003 in VEH_YEAR column. The query works if I have a value 2003 in VEH_YEAR column but A_COUNT is null.

Comment: SELECT NVL((select A_COUNT from MYTABLE where VEH_YEAR = '2003'), 0) A_COUNT from dual;     This worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better version of your uery would be, using an `Aggregate` function like `MAX` before using `NVL`.

```
select NVL(MAX(A_COUNT),0) from MYTABLE where VEH_YEAR = '2003';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NVL((select A_COUNT from MYTABLE where VEH_YEAR = '2003'), 0) A_COUNT from dual;
```

This worked.